# Cleaning new lines in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe in R that was cleaned in order to get informative parts of some URLS. It refuses to print the first element when I request to print the whole dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(my_data[1,])

#provided for clarity
[1] c("https:
1073 Levels:  ... Zloc-60-Qt-WeatherShield-Storage-Box-Clear
```

its a very long list....

```
print(mydata)

549818028
311                                                      Quilted-        
Northern-Ultra-Plush-24-Double-Rolls-Toilet-Paper-Bath-Tissue
312                                                                                                                   
49883627
313                                                                       
Great-Value-Bath-Tissue-Ultra-Strong-24-Double-Rolls
314                                                                                                                  
910596048
315                                                    Quilted- 
Northern-Ultra-Soft-Strong-Bathroom-Tissue-2-Ply-White-12-rolls
316                                                                                                                  
170741025
317                                                                               
Great-Value-1000-Sheets-Bath-Tissue-12-Rolls
318                                                                                                                   
32631328
319                                                                      
Great-Value-Bath-Tissue-Everyday-Soft-24-Double-Rolls
320                                                                                                                  
118420428
321                                                                       
Great-Value-Bath-Tissue-Ultra-Strong-12-Double-Rolls
322                                                                                                                  
935578946
```

Things seem to be ok but when I print any element I have this extra 
snippet of text on the bottom:

```
> print(jacks_new_list[315,])
[1] Quilted-Northern-Ultra-Soft-Strong-Bathroom-Tissue-2-Ply-White- 
12-rolls
1073 Levels:  ... Zloc-60-Qt-WeatherShield-Storage-Box-Clear
```

I'm trying to remove this snippet that now appears on each element line
"1073 Levels:  ... Zloc-60-Qt-WeatherShield-Storage-Box-Clear"
I've tried to get rid of it using grep with no success so far. I also can't decide if there's actually a new line there or not because I'm not seeing one actually written in the text anywhere.

Eventually this will be a two column list of titles with their corresponding number. So the numbers need to be legible and junk free so they can be used later.

FYI the three digit numbers are the indices, and are not part of the string info in the dataframe element

Comment: How did you import your data? It just looks like your character values were turned into factors. That snippet is only printed to the screen, it's not actually "in" the data. To turn factors into characters, you can use `as.character()` on that column. Maybe read more about this common R data type: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing a factor, this is the normal output. 
Here is an example:

```
iris$Species <- as.factor(iris$Species)
print(iris$Species[1])
```

Convert the variable factor to character:

```
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
print(iris$Species[1])
```

The real question is why you even care what the printout looks like.

Comment: I am not so much worried about the print output "looking" a certain way, I just wasn't sure whether that extra string was actually part of the element somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to remove the extra information about levels of factor:

```
print(as.character(jacks_new_list[315,]))
```